# How to rewrite below code so that I get expected output

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The objective is to read list of known files from amazon s3 and create a single file in s3 at some output path. Each file is tab separated. I have to extract first element from each line and and assign it a numeric value in increasing order. Numeric value and element should be tab separated in the new file which would be created. I am using spark with scala to perform operations on RDDs.

### Expected output

1 qwerty
2 asdf
...
...
67892341 ghjk

### Current output

1 qwerty
2 asdf
...
...
456721 tyui
1 sdfg
2 swerr
...
...
263523 gkfk
...
...
512346 ghjk

So, basically as the computation is happening on distributed cluster, the global variable `counter` is getting initiated on each machine. How can I rewrite the code so that I get the desired output. Below is the code snippet.

```
    def getReqCol() = {
     val myRDD = sc.textFile("s3://mybucket/fileFormatregex")
     var counter = 0
     val mbLuidCol = myRDD.map(x => x.split("\t")).map(col =>col(0)).map(row => {
       def inc(acc : Int) = {
         counter = acc + 1
       }
     inc(counter)
     counter + "\t" + row
   })
   row.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("s3://mybucket/outputPath")
 }
```

Comment: You're trying to index each row in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all you need is [`RDD.zipWithIndex()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@zipWithIndex():org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(T,Long)]):

```
val myRDD = 
  sc
   .textFile("s3://mybucket/fileFormatregex")
   .map(col => col(0))
   .zipWithIndex()
   .map(_.swap)
   .sortByKey(true)
   .repartition(1)
   .saveAsTextFile("s3://mybucket/outputPath")
```

Comment: zipWithIndex().map(row => row.swap).sortByKey(true).map(row => row._1 + "\t" + row._2). I was able to get required output after adding above piece of code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @zizouraj Awesome. Glad it helped.